# Java: Prevent subclass from providing a different interface than base class

Tags: java

Is there a means to prevent a subclass from exposing public methods other than those defined in the base class, at compile-time?

For example:

```
abstract public class AClass {

   abstract public void anAllowedMethod();

}

public class BClass extends Aclass {

    public void anAllowedMethod() {

    }

    public void anAdditionalNonAllowedMethod() {

    }

    private void thisMethodIsAllowedBecauseItsNotPublic() {

    }

}
```

Perhaps there is some keyword I can use in AClass to declare the subclass can only implemented the methods defined in AClass (ie. "anAllowedMethod()")?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this.

Comment: To ensure that these subclasses are being used correctly. In a project I'm working on, some developers are adding extra methods to the subclass which are not necessary (could otherwise be achieved through the existing interface), and makes it impossible to use the object correctly if you don't know it's derived type. It will simplify things if we know that the "the client" only needs to know the interface of the base class.

Comment: One thing you could do is encourage people using your API not to declare variables of type BClass. I'm thinking of the way `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>()` is considered to be better than `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>()`. So you an instantiate BClass but your variable type is AClass so you'll probably never end up using `anAdditionalNonAllowedMethod()`

Comment: Yeah I guess that's what I'm trying to do, but in a passive aggressive way :)

Comment: Hm... Well here's what I'm thinking: If the things the developers are adding can be done using the existing interface of AClass, ask them why they wanted to add the new methods. If there is no good reason, try to phase them out. If they have a good reason, implement them in AClass and then try to do what I said in the last comment: Use AClass, not BClass for variable types whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage of the game it is probably too late, but what you could do is create a final class with the relevant methods that takes a delegate in its constructor of a different type that has actual implementation, and have the methods of the final class call the delegate. That way whatever they add to the delegate won't be callable at all.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. When you define a class and say that it extends/implements another class it must adhere to the contract of the class it extends/implements. There is no restriction on containing the said class' behaviour further.

> In a project I'm working on, some developers are adding extra methods to the subclass which are not necessary

As I see, this effectively means that your *design* is going to pieces due to developers doing what they please (by adding new public behaviour to objects).

Unfortunately, if you don't manage your *design* once it is in the implementation phase (coding) bad things are bound to happen. Please consider a process of review (automated/manual)

Answer (score 2):

You could make the class final so it can't be subclassed (can't be abstract, of course), but design it to use composition/delegation, so instead of varying implementation via subclasses, you vary it by what strategy objects you use in the composition of instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support this. However, if you want clients of your class to use only the interface you defined, you could declare a java interface and then use a factory to create objects that implement that interface. Therefore the clients could only call methods from the interface. Of course if someone is determined they could find ways around this (like doing an explicit cast), but if people are intentionally breaking your design, you have bigger problems to contend with.

Comment: I personally think this is the (mostly) correct answer. With Java you really should be coding to interfaces anyway. However, rather than writing all the factories, the latest fad/trend is to create implementation classes using dependency injection (Spring, EJB3, Guice, etc.). And honestly, I find DI very, very easy to work with.

Comment: Agree. Once you have lots of factories, using a DI framework is the next logical step, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

not in the general case...

But...

If you are trying to block specific interfaces, you could declare a final method in your abstract base class with the name of the method(s) from the interface.  That wouldn't prevent anyone from making a sub-class implement the interface, but it would certainly prevent them from doing anything with the method calls.

I suppose that you could use reflection at runtime to disallow things...

And you could absolutely do this with an AOP container.  I just saw additional comments on the OP, and I see now what you are going for.  My recommendation is to treat this as something that should be managed at the source control level - either have a test mode that does runtime checks for the problem (i.e. treat this as an implementation unit test), or (if you are using a CI system) have this sort of thing tested at check-in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered **final**?

I know, it's not what you asked for, but there's no feature like this in the language.  Or, for that matter, in any language I know - and I know a lot.

Which leads us to trying to find another way to do what you want to do - to meet the underlying need.

However, since I can't imagine a sensible reason to do this, I'm stumped.

Why do you want to prevent a subclass from adding methods?  What is it that you fear will happen?

Comment: I don't think he would want to use final because he stil wants the sublcasses to define their own anOllowedMethod.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others on the thread that what you are trying to do isn't desireable. However, I believe you could use reflection to make sure any methods declared are ones you are expecting.

```
Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
for (Method method : methods)
{
    if (method.getName() ... ) // check to make sure method is expected
    {
        .... // if method not expected throw an exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest doing this ... for fear that someone might be silly enough to implement it!

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, but it would do what he is asking. :-)